# Scroll a web view programmatically

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp

Is there any way in which I can programmatically scroll a webview control in a UWP app?

It should work like the page down functionality in a web browser. Which will automatically scroll to next page of the document displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject JS script to page HTML and then run it.

```
WebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { 'your script here' });
```